# CalendarAgent wants to connect to wunderground

Tags: calendar

Odd one.
Without (knowingly) changing anything (of course SOMETHING must have changed) when I booted up Apple Calendar the other day I got this alert from Little Snitch:

> CalendarAgent via com.apple.WeatherKitService.xpc wants to connect to
>   api.wunderground.com on TCP port 443 (https)

Any idea why or how that would happen?
I don't sync to any Calendars that I know of, and use the Calendar infrequently.

OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weather Underground is the provider for Apple's weather data in OS X/macOS (and iOS). Calendar.app downloads weather information for calendar events with a set location.

As soon as you add a location to a calendar event Calendar.app will try to fetch the weather conditions if it's only a few days in the future.

[image: Weather display in Calendar.app]

Location services (System Preferences > Security > Privacy) does not effect the download of weather information.

Comment: Little Snitch has got a lot more twitchy since v4.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point. cheakypawl, can you please include the version of Little Snitch that you are using (v4 or v3)?

Comment: Forgot to mention earlier - I actually saw the same warning this morning - after checking who 'wunderground' was, I let it through.

Comment: I had no idea about Calendar having weather? Never seen weather in the Calendar, where is it? I use V3 Snitch, V4 sucks (tried & reverted - ugliest large interface) I do not have and have never had any location services ever switched, so it's not to do with the system preferences of Mac Os.

Comment: Create an event for tomorrow and enter a valid location (Toronto, Canada, for example). You will see the weather for the specific time of day.

Comment: I think oa- might be on to something. I have never entered a location in that option to in Calendar until a week or so ago. Maybe that has triggered this?

Comment: Yes, this looks like the reason for the Little Snitch notification. :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Location Services being on or off makes no difference to this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66378/discussion-between-oa-and-cheakypawl).

Comment: Had no idea about the CHAT option. Next time! User oa had all the info I needed.